# Cup anemometre can measure 3D wind component?

Tags: measurements

As part of my PhD thesis I am looking for information about anemometres.

I have heard that cup anemometre can only measure the `x` and `y` component of the wind, the `z` being left out because it measures the wind thanks to moving part.

I have been unable, so far, to find a source for that affirmation, is it true?

I know that cup anemometre are slower than sonic to measure sudden wind changes (speed and directions) due to the inertia of the mechanics, but nothing about wind component.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm VTCing this as homework because you need to show what theory/models you've tried to explain/refute this claim.

Comment: That is the whole issue. After reading how anemometres work there is no mention whatsoever about limitations for cup anemometres to measure 3D wind.

Comment: _I have heard that cup anemometre can only measure the x and y component of the wind, the z being left out_ If you will rotate cup anemometer $90^o$,- so that it's shaft would be horizontal,- then `x,y` should capture vertical wind speed components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searches I have found two online sources confirming my statement:

1. https://www.omega.ca/en/resources/anemometers
2. https://www.eas.ualberta.ca/jdwilson/EAS327/eas327wind.html

As well as a book "Wind Energy: theory and practise" p40. which says: "cup anemometers are the sensor type most commonly used for for the measurements of near-horizontal wind".

If this helps anyone else in the future!